# json-ld keeping some objects in pure json

Tags: json, json-ld

I have json-ld and you would like to add "key": "value" where value is a object but I want to keep it in pure json. Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `{"first":{"first-first":"I am a JSON object inside a JSON object!"},"second":{"second-first":"I am another object inside a different key of a JSON!"}}` Something like this? You can call the value like `json-id.first.first-first`; I recommend `json-id.first["first-first"]` because I used a **-** in my key.

Comment: Actually I meant: to exclude some inside object from changes during json-ld expand (http://json-ld.org/playground/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet, but likely to be included in a 1.1 community release.